# Uploadify - Change temp name to time and upload - PHP

Tags: php, image, upload, uploadify

I want to change the name of the uploaded file, to the current time by using `time()` but i cant seem to figger out where to insert the new time name ?

can some one try look at this ?

```
<?php
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $newName = time(); <-- Should be the new temp name, insted of the uploaded one.
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_GET['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
}

echo '1';
?>
```

Comment: ` $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name']` this line...change to whatever u need..`$_FILES['Filedata']['name']` change from here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_FILES['Filedata']['name']` has your filename, you can replace that but first you need to get the file's extension if it's not the same all the time.

```
$p = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
$newName = time() . "." . $p['extension'];
$targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $newName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get the extension of the uploaded file ..
$ext = end(explode('.', $_FILES['Filedata']['name']));
// Set the target location to your filename, plus the extension
$targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $newName . '.' . $ext;
```

Answer (score 0):

The code should be:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $newName = time(); <-- Should be the new temp name, insted of the uploaded one.
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_GET['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $newName . '.EXT';

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
}

echo '1';
?>
```

Comment: This is working fine, but i cant get the extension to work tho. can i go xxx['name']['extension'] ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$_FILES['Filedata']['name']` with `time()`